# Is there way to sync the shell yank buffer and the clipboard?

Tags: bash, x11, clipboard

In a terminal I copy a line by `Ctrl+a` and `Ctrl+k`.
I want to copy the text into clipboard when another window become active so that I can use the text another application, like a text editor or a browser.

Is there way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of terminal do you use?
In both gnome-terminal and xfce4-terminal you just add the Shift key to the standard shortcuts, or you can use the Edit menu. So:

Shift+Ctrl+c Copy
Shift+Ctrl+v Paste
Shift+Ctrl+a Select All

Then in an another window you can use the standard paste keys to paste the content. Emacs editor is a bit peculiar here, e.g. the way to paste from the clipboard is via Yank (default Ctrl+y).